# Spam identifier

Tags: python, pandas, svm, gridsearchcv

I have a code that helps checking if a mail is ham or spam,I can get the accuracy in general, but I want to know the percentage of ham and spam that was correct.

this is the code: v2 are the mails and v1 the labels

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB, GaussianNB
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

data = pd.read_csv('D:/Descargas/spam.csv', encoding='utf-8')

x_data=data['v2']
y_data=data['v1']
 
split =(int)(0.8*data.shape[0])
x_train=x_data[:split]
x_test=x_data[split:]
y_train=y_data[:split]
y_test=y_data[split:]

count_vector = CountVectorizer()  
extracted_features = count_vector.fit_transform(x_train)

tuned_parameters = {'kernel': ['rbf','linear'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}
model = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(), tuned_parameters)
model.fit(extracted_features,y_train)
 
print("Model Trained Successfully!")

print("Accuracy of the model is: ",model.score(count_vector.transform(x_test),y_test)*100)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think this solves your problem:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
# Calculate the classification report
report = classification_report(y_test, model.predict(count_vector.transform(x_test)))
# Print the report
print(report)
```